# What are `Recurrent products` and `nominal products`?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

Are there any products as `recurrent` products and `nominal` products apart from the default 6 types of products ? If so can anyone provide a brief explanation about them ? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/

Comment: That doesn't contain anything about ` recurrent products`

Comment: Recurring Profiles = Recurrent products...I think

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll go through the link and put the absorbed knowledge here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll put a brief description about nominal products which I triggered out from the link provided by Marius.

`Nominal Item` : After recurring profile is enabled for a particular product, then that product becomes a nominal item.

Nominal items have the following qualities.

1. Nominal items are not added to regular totals (taxes, subtotal, and grand total).
2. Gift cards, store credit, and reward points are not applied to nominal items.
3. Subtotal, tax, shipping, and other nominal charges are separately calculated for a nominal item.
4. All nominal totals are summed into the nominal grand total.
5. Payment methods available for nominal products are limited to PayPal Express Checkout only.
6. The list of available shipping methods during the shopping cart checkout is restricted to the fixed only (Fixed, Table Rates, and Free).

Comment: Has the answer changed in terms of Magento 1.9.x? I know, its an old answer, but I'd love to get an update for it, if its nessecary.