# Why are quotes not converted to is_active=0 after checkout? M1/M2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, shopping-cart, quote

When looking at sales_flat_quote (M1) or quote (M2) table, there are many quotes stuck at is_active=1. Even though there is a sale in sales_flat_order / sales_order.

This does not seem to have a relation to the state of the order (finding complete/processing/canceled orders), nor payment method (finding paypal, checkmo and 3rd party gateway orders).

When joining the quote and sales tables to find orders with 'open' quotes, I find many results on several shops that we manage.

I'm using this query on M1:

`` SELECT `sales_flat_order`.`state`,
       `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id`,
       `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id`,
       `sales_flat_order`.`created_at`,
       `sales_flat_order`.`quote_id`,
       `sales_flat_quote`.`is_active`,
       `sales_flat_quote`.`customer_email`,
       `sales_flat_order_payment`.`method`
FROM `sales_flat_order`
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_quote ON `sales_flat_order`.`quote_id`=`sales_flat_quote`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` ON sales_flat_order.`entity_id`=sales_flat_order_payment.`parent_id`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`is_active` = 1; ``

and this one on M2:

`` SELECT `sales_order`.`state`,
       `sales_order`.`increment_id`,
       `sales_order`.`entity_id`,
       `sales_order`.`created_at`,
       `sales_order`.`quote_id`,
       `quote`.`is_active`,
       `quote`.`customer_email`,
       `sales_order_payment`.`method`
FROM `sales_order`
LEFT JOIN quote ON `sales_order`.`quote_id`=`quote`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON sales_order.`entity_id`=sales_order_payment.`parent_id`
WHERE `quote`.`is_active` = 1; ``

Am I looking at this the wrong way? Can people confirm the same thing for their M1/M2 shop?

Comment: guys, have you got any solution? i have also seen some succes order which quote have is_active value 1 .

Comment: 2023 using OpenMage (Magento 1) and still having this issue. It's becoming much more common and causing errors due to orders being submitted to PayPal using the same reserved_order_id. It seems there is an unknown error occurring in the checkout that causes an order to successfully be placed, but the customer either hangs on the checkout page or is returned to the cart with all their products still in there (looking like the order didn't complete.) After much research I still haven't been able to recreate the error but it is happening approx 1/20 orders.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that there are a large number of returned rows on several stores that I have access to for your Magento 1 query above.  These don't seem to be related with a specific payment method.

There are a number of reaons why the is_active flag is set to 0 or 1.

- is_active always starts as 1 for cart/quote created by frontend
- is_active is 0 for quotes created from admin
- To load quote by Customer Id, is_active = 1 is taken into account
- When quote is converted to order, is_active becomes 0
- When you create a quote via API, is_active is always 0

There are a number of reasons in the Magento flow why the is_active flag may remain at 1.

`Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php` has a `$_shouldInactivateQuote` flag which is checked against when the `_inactivateQuote()` method is called during `submitOrder()`.

This wouldn't allow the flag to be set to 0 if:

- Nominal items are included in the basket ([What are `Recurrent products` and `nominal products`?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/what-are-recurrent-products-and-nominal-products)) - function `submitAll()`
- If an exception is thrown when Nominal items are submitted
- If payment fails (this could be an issue with the payment gateway whereby the order is submitted, but payment fails or it is handled by another process?)

Additionally, there are a number of times in the codebase when the flag is specifically set to true (1).

- Within `Mage/Persistent/Model/Observer.php` - `setQuoteGuest` - would be worth checking if these orders were completed as a guest by adding `customer_id` to your query above.
- If checkout fails - see `Mage/PayPal/Helper/Checkout.php` & `Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php`

Comment: Hi Douglas, thanks for the elaborate write-up. When I add customer_id to the query I'm finding entries with and without id.
Also there are a lot of orders either cancelled or complete, so those are with a successful payment.. Still not really getting grip on this :(